# Swift3 Как убрать звуки уведомлений?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift3

Можно ли программно отключить все звуки уведомлений во время работы приложения? Если да, то как это написать в коде?

Answer (score 0):

Чужие звуки (звуки других приложений) вы не можете отключить, это системные настройки.
Свои и отключать не надо - нотификация приходит прямо в ваше приложение, вы сами ее обрабатываете.